# Ajax on.('keydown') events are stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading JSON into the browser when the search field is focused. I will then iterate over the JSON objects to find results in real time 'on keydown'.

The problem I am facing is described in the console after the first block of code

**Ajax Call**

```
$('.table-search').on('focus', function() { // load JSON when search field focused
    var input = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: cml_theme.ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true,
        data: {
            action: 'get_coins_as_json' // loads JSON
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result) // does not incrementally stack (works fine)
            $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
                console.log(e); // incrementally stacks (see below)
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Console**

The following is what is logged at each keydown, not a cumulative log i.e. on the 3rd focus it "spams" 3 rows to console. I only want 1 row to be triggered.

*On first focus and 1 keydown:*

```
r.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keydown", target: input.table-search {...}
```

*On second focus and 1 keydown:*

```
r.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keydown", target: input.table-search {...}
r.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keydown", target: input.table-search {...}
```

*On third focus and 1 keydown:*

```
r.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keydown", target: input.table-search {...}
r.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keydown", target: input.table-search {...}
r.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keydown", target: input.table-search {...}
```

**EDIT**

My lack of understanding of event listeners caused this issue. I've added the following line at the start of the success function to clear the stacking event listeners:

```
$(document).off('keydown'); // clear event listeners
```

Comment: every time as you call to the backoffice operation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: everry time you call on('focus', and call ajax operation, stack one more

Comment: Everytime on keydown - see console.log(e) which is where the problem is. I will update the code to show that console.log(result) works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your success is called you add a callback function for the `onKeyDown` event. So every time you focus on the search bar you add a `onKeyDownListener` which get called for each key down event. Why are you adding the key down listener only after the ajax call was successful?

Comment: I need to be able to use data from the variable `result` in the `.on('keydown')` function. How would I go about clearing the listeners before running the code?

Comment: thank you Rainer; added this line and it's resolved  `$(document).off('keydown'); // clear event listeners`

Comment: @Nick Just chain it `$(document).off('keydown').on('keydown', function(e) ...` etc etc

Comment: Thanks, out of interest is that purely for readability/simplicity/spare a line?